# getting the font size on cocoa in c++

Tags: c++, cocoa, fonts, size, wxwidgets

ALL,

This is the function I'm using to get the font size on Windows:

```
void wxMyGetCharSize(WXHWND wnd, int *x, int *y, const wxFont& the_font)
{
    TEXTMETRIC tm;
    HDC dc = ::GetDC((HWND) wnd);
    HFONT was = 0;

    HFONT fnt = (HFONT)the_font.GetResourceHandle(); // const_cast
    if ( fnt )
        was = (HFONT) SelectObject(dc,fnt);
    GetTextMetrics(dc, &tm);
    if ( fnt && was )
    {
        SelectObject(dc,was);
    }
    ReleaseDC((HWND)wnd, dc);
    if ( x )
        *x = tm.tmAveCharWidth;
    if ( y )
        *y = tm.tmHeight + tm.tmExternalLeading;
}
```

Problem is I need to do the same on the Mac-Cocoa side.
And I'd like to have such a function in plain C++ code or explain how do I use .mm file with cpp one.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You nee to do change the .m file in cocoa to .mm file and you can write whatever C++ function you want to write.

Comment: 2 things: first of all I'm not Mac/Cocoa programmer so need guidance on how to achieve this functionality - getting the font size. Second - how do I use this .mm file along with my cpp file? Thank you.

Comment: Just add the .mm file in cocoa and try

Comment: Yes, I want this code in Cocoa, unless you know the way to make it work on the Mac.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using wxWidgets anyhow, what's wrong with using [wxWindow::GetTextExtent()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_window.html#ac9cd7b4472d5419e518f69311914466f)??